# Object Identity

Tags: python, list, tuples

**Python 3.7**

*Why this:*

```
a,b,c = [], [], []
print(a is b, b is c)
```

*is different than this:*

```
a,b,c = ([],) * 3
print(a is b, b is c)
```

Comment: In the first case you create three list objects: `[], [], []`. In the second case you only create one list object: `[]`.

Comment: `[], [], []` creates 3 independent list objects, `([],) * 3` copies the reference to the same list object 3 times.